# Using Tensorflow GPU On Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get my GPU to work on tensorflow 2.3.0 on anaconda. I have gone and installed Visual Studio, cuDNN and CUDA Toolkit, making sure that each one is the latest working on the tensorflow package (7.6 and 10.1 respectively I believe). I have then tried checking if my GPU is recognized but have been giving the following when running the code.

[image]
[image]

Not quite sure how to go about finding what to do since I've tried reinstalling the package as well as try keras gpu and others but nothing has fixed it yet.

Comment: Have you added CUDA to Path?

Comment: I believe so, I've added an edit so you can see the environment paths

Comment: This is on windows correct?

Comment: hi, did you install cudatoolkit on the anaconda channel? you can watch this video to create a Cuda enabled environment on the  anaconda https://youtu.be/1QTgf3svtQw

Comment: I did CUDA and cuDNN separately and then move the dll in. I will give this a look

Comment: The installation engine has a problem for `Tensorflow-gpu2.3` in Anaconda on Windows 10. Workaround is to explicitly specify the correct tensorflow build: `conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0`. Conda works best to install tensorflow because it installs the `CUDA toolkit` and the proper version of `cuDNN`. Thanks!